# Hangfire: Calling methods with delay doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, asp.net-core, hangfire

I have an ASP.NET core application and wanted to use Hangfire for some background tasks.
I set up Hangfire as it was described in the official documentation, and I can call usual background tasks.
However, I have problems with calling the methods with delay.

```
public void Configure(/*other params*/ IBackgroundJobClient backgroundJobsClient)
{
   //Other code
   
   backgroundJobsClient.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Method"));
   backgroundJobsClient.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Delayed Method"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
}
```

I have only "Method" output in the console.

After waiting for a minute, I have an exception in my console:

> Hangfire.Processing.BackgroundExecution[0]
> Execution DelayedJobScheduler is in the Failed state now due to an exception, execution will be retried no more than in 00:00:04
> Hangfire.PostgreSql.PostgreSqlDistributedLockException: Could not place a lock on the resource 'HangFire:locks:schedulepoller': Lock timeout.
> at Hangfire.PostgreSql.PostgreSqlDistributedLock.PostgreSqlDistributedLock_Init_Transaction(String resource, TimeSpan timeout, IDbConnection connection, PostgreSqlStorageOptions options)
> at Hangfire.PostgreSql.PostgreSqlDistributedLock..ctor(String resource, TimeSpan timeout, IDbConnection connection, PostgreSqlStorageOptions options)
> at Hangfire.PostgreSql.PostgreSqlConnection.AcquireDistributedLock(String resource, TimeSpan timeout)
> at Hangfire.Server.DelayedJobScheduler.UseConnectionDistributedLock[T](JobStorage storage, Func`2 action) at Hangfire.Server.DelayedJobScheduler.EnqueueNextScheduledJobs(BackgroundProcessContext context) at Hangfire.Server.DelayedJobScheduler.Execute(BackgroundProcessContext context) at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundProcessDispatcherBuilder.ExecuteProcess(Guid executionId, Object state) at Hangfire.Processing.BackgroundExecution.Run(Action`2 callback, Object state)
> !!! Could not place a lock on the resource 'HangFire:locks:schedulepoller': Lock timeout.

So, I suppose there is some issue with delayed methods initialization.
Could someone help me with that? Probably I didn't setup Hangfire correctly for ASP.NET core.

Comment: Seems like you are getting a lock timeout on your postgress database: ` Could not place a lock on the resource 'HangFire:locks:schedulepoller': Lock timeout` . Are you using `DisableConcurrentExecutionAttribute` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. This attribute helped me to get rid of the exception (I've wrapped Console.WriteLine with own method and applied the attribute to it). However, I still can't see the output of the delayed task.

Comment: Please refer to [this tutorial](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-core-applications.html) to use Hangfire in the Asp.net core application, I have followed the steps to configure the Settings and register the services, then the delay method works well on my side. Finally, if still not working, it is better to post the related code in the ConfigureServices method, so that we can know how do you register the Hangfire service.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I read this tutorial when I started using the Hangfire. I was able to find a cause of the problem. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found a solution.
The date stores in the Hangfire database in UTC format.
I didn't know that, and official [documentation](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/calling-methods-with-delay.html) doesn't say anything about that.
The correct code should look something like this:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem as below.

There is **lock** **table** in the **Hangfire tables**. I deleted all data in the lock table, my issue solved.